# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrappers' when trying to load file using Pickle

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I'm trying to load a machine learning model `.sav` file using `Pickle`

but it always outputs the error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrappers'`

I tried adding the import wrapper after a `pip intall wrapper` but it didn't solve my problem,
and I didn't seem to find stuff related to this anywhere else

this is my code :

```py
import pandas
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import pickle
import wrapper

with open('C:\\Users\\SBS\\IMPORTED_DATA\\Trend_Perfect_SVC\\machine_learning_model.sav', 'rb') as file:
    response = pickle.load(file)
```

This is the complete error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5184/102863235.py in <module>
      1 with open('C:\\Users\\SBS\\IMPORTED_DATA\\Trend_Perfect_SVC\\machine_learning_model.sav', 'rb') as file:
----> 2     response = pickle.load(file)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wrappers'
```

I'm running this code on my local machine using the `JupyterLab` environment

I can provide a link to the file I'm using if it helps
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would seem like you have imported it but not installed it? Have you looked at this: [Potential Answer](https://copypaste.guru/WhereIsMyPythonModule/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-module-wrapper)? Have you tried running: ```pip install module-wrapper```

Answer (score 0):

try import wrappers instead of import wrapper. Just an suggestion. That's all one can suggest with the info you've provided.

Comment: trying to perform a `pip install wrappers` outputs `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wrappers (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7, 0.1.8, 0.1.9)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wrappers`  so i figured i'm missing something